# After upgrading to the latest docker image from yesterday, nextcloud connections are broken

Tags: mariadb, docker

After upgrading to https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/mariadb/latest/images/sha256-dae04d35ddd4ca837c1d330962eab9b5577325d1751e1877203b3fafe67b5daa?context=explore&tab=vulnerabilities automatically, all of a sudden nextcloud connections fail with

```
Aborted connection 43 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.18.0.5' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
```

Rolling back the image to 2f62d6fb2c8b solves that problem - is that a problem with the image or did something change in a breaking way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There was a [reissue](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/pull/16293), repull the image.